# CodeLens style in-context information in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, codelens

For a while now, newer versions of Visual Studio have been able to display in-line information for methods, fields etc relating to how many times they may have been referenced or changed and who changed the code last. This feature is known as CodeLens.

[image: Image showing CodeLens feature]

Is there any plugin or feature in IntelliJ IDEA similar to this that would be able to display information on an individual class/field/method basis?

Comment: I think you can create a feature request at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new

Answer (score 20, accepted):

(22-Aug-2022 updated) The hints from git blame are also available in the latest `IntelliJ IDEA`.
[image]

==================

(For CodeLens function references feature) Now it's a built-in feature after version `IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1`.

You can enable it from:

Ref: https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2020/03/intellij-idea-2020-1-beta2/

Answer (score 15):

There is no such plugin (yet).

You can of course right click the left gutter (gray editor to the left of the editor) and select "Annotate". That gives you at least the *last* edit per line.

More similar to your desired feature (but unfortunately not inline):
Select some text (e.g. a method), then right-click Git -> Show History for Selection.

Comment: This feature is same as one provided by gitlens. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 14):

Now there is JetBrains plugin named [**GitToolBox**](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7499-gittoolbox/).

It has some similar functionality, including the current line "blame annotation" at the end of the line with detailed commit information:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This feature is available for Rider, but not for IntelliJ yet.
In Rider it's called [Code Vision](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2018/12/10/code-vision-rider-enriching-editor-contextual-information-navigation/)

You can vote for this feature request in IntelliJ IDEA [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-170438?_ga=2.162694332.1689252311.1575986144-978454811.1568984925)